# Can the multiplicative product of bijective functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be bijective?

Tags: functions

Given two functions $f$ and $g$, which are bijective $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, can $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$ also be bijective on $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

I can prove no such $h$ exists if $f$ and $g$ are continuous: $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ must be $0$ for the same value of $x$ (else there would be two zeroes for $h(x)$).

Then for all $y \leq x$, $f(y)$ is either always positive, or always negative, and similarly for $g$. The functions must take the oppositve sign for all $y \geq x$. Then either $f$ and $g$ always have the same sign (so $h$ is always positive) or $f$ and $g$ always have oppposite signs (so $h$ is always negative).

However, this kind of argument doesn't get me anywhere once I let $f$ and $g$ be non-continous. This feels like it should be a common question, but I couldn't find an answer written anywhere.

Comment: "Multiplicative product" just means "product", right?

Comment: I think the usual term is _pointwise_ product.

Comment: See [Can a pointwise product of $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ bijections be also a bijection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2092547/1256533)

Comment: I believe that, for **any** infinite group $G$, there exist bijections $f,g:G\to G$ such that the product $x\mapsto f(x)g(x)$ is also a bijection. I would do it with well-ordering and transfinite recursion. Glancing at the old answers, it seems that it can be done constructively at least in the case of the group $\mathbb R^\times$.